# Customise Tensorboard with buttons, sliders, personal functions

Tags: tensorflow, button, slider, tensorboard

Is it possible to **customise Tensorboard** with our own buttons, sliders and colours to create a sort of web application ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are able to do this by creating a Tensorboard plugin. This [blog post](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/09/build-your-own-machine-learning.html) can give you a good idea of what capabilities you can add via a plugin. You can follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example/blob/master/README.md) to get started.

Broadly speaking, the 3 parts of a Tensorboard plugin are:

1. A summary op that gathers the data you need from the Tensorflow session.
2. A post-processing python script that serves that data to the web client.
3. Front-end code to display and interact with the data.

As it sounds like your interests are mostly just pertaining to the presentation, it is likely that you can use data already already gathered by Tensorflow and steps 1 & 2 may be very small or non-existent for your case.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Tensorboard plugins has moved to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/ADDING_A_PLUGIN.md).